# ImportError: Access denied

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows-7

I reinstalled Pillow through pip and now I'm getting the following error (if not running the app as administrator):

```
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw, ImageFont
  File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\PIL\Image.py", line 53, in <module>
    from PIL import _imaging as core
ImportError: DLL load failed: Access denied.
```

Everything worked fine before, how to fix this?

Comment: Do you use PIL with Django? Pillow is the preferred image manipulation library from Django==1.6 [Django 1.6 release notes](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/releases/1.6/)

Comment: Check `icacls C:\Python\lib\site-packages\PIL\_imaging.pyd`. The `Users` group should have at least `RX` access (read and execute).